# Rcpp to use third party library Kvaser kvmlib

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am looking for the best approach to use the Kvaser SDK (https://www.kvaser.com/developer-blog/get-hardware-kvaser-sdk-libraries/) to convert files from a can Memorator into a useable format within an R Shiny app. The data files are logged on a device as a .KMF file. There are functions in the kvmlib library to convert this file to a .KME50 file, which can then be converted to a .csv file using functions in the kvlclib library.

I want to be able to use the function calls in this API from within R. I decided to use Rcpp and try to connect to the libraries that way. I put all the header files I need into a folder along with the canlib.dll files and made that my R workspace. Whenever I try to run sourceCpp for a .cpp file containing any of the kvlclib.h, kvmlib.h, or windows.h headers I get a series of errors.

Could someone please advise if my approach seems correct. I think it probably has to do with connecting to these libraries, I am new to C++ and linking to third party libraries. Included is an example of the errors I am getting.

[image: Rcpp errors]

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total / n;
}
```

Comment: Did you check first whether you can compile in cpp the example with the headers? By this you can check whether that is a cpp internal problem (compatibility issues) or not.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include (a selection) of the error messages from the console window instead of a screen shot.

Answer (score 3):

Both `windows.h` and some R headers define macros like `Realloc`. You can inhibit the R headers from doing so by using

```
#define STRICT_R_HEADERS
#include <Rcpp.h>
```

As @SymbolixAU mentions in the comments: In the context of a package you can also use `src/Makevars`:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-DSTRICT_R_HEADERS
```

Comment: similarly you can define this in the `Makevars` (like [this example](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/jsonify/blob/master/src/Makevars#L4) )